# How to get Value of specific cell of datagridview in Winform application

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, datagridview

I have a dataGridView which contains the check-boxes in its first column. Now as per my requirement i have to get the value of `Employee No` column for the row whose checkbox has been clicked on another button click event.Also how to get the value for multiple checkbox selected .

Here is my code..

```
    private void btn_load_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Select", System.Type.GetType("System.Boolean"));
        dt.Columns.Add("Employee No");
        dt.Columns.Add("Employee Name");
        dt.Columns.Add("Join Date");

        DataRow dr;

        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["Select"] = false;
            dr["Employee No"] = 1000 + i;
            dr["Employee Name"] = "Employee " + i;
            dr["Join Date"] = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }

        dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = true;
        dataGridView1.AllowUserToDeleteRows = true;
        dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt; 
    } 

    private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //I need the Employee Id values here
    }
```

Please help me .Thanks in advance..

Comment: using DataGridView_CellContentClick event capture Employee Id value

Comment: Private Sub DataGridView_CellContentClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView.CellContentClick

        If DataGridView.Rows(DataGridView.CurrentCell.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value = True Then
   'do something
   End If
End Sub

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use the DataSource property:

```
    private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
       int[] employeeIds = (dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).Rows
           .Cast<DataRow>()
           .Where(r => (bool)r["Select"])
           .Select(r => Convert.ToInt32(r["Employee No"]))
           .ToArray();
    }
```

and use the System.Linq namespace.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have bound your DataTable to the grids DataSource, you could make `dt` a class variable and use that to check the selected ones.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private DataTable dt;

    private void btn_load_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Select", System.Type.GetType("System.Boolean"));
        dt.Columns.Add("Employee No");
        dt.Columns.Add("Employee Name");
        dt.Columns.Add("Join Date");

        DataRow dr;

        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["Select"] = false;
            dr["Employee No"] = 1000 + i;
            dr["Employee Name"] = "Employee " + i;
            dr["Join Date"] = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }

        dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = true;
        dataGridView1.AllowUserToDeleteRows = true;
        dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }

    private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //I need the Employee Id values here
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            if ((bool)row["Select"] == true)
            {

            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose to have a global variable in your form class declared as

```
List<int> empIDs = new List<int> empIDs();
```

Now in your click event you could write

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    empIDs.Clear();
    foreach(DataGridViewRow r in dgv.Rows)
    {
        DataGridViewCheckBoxCell c = r.Cells["Select"] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell;
        if(Convert.ToBoolean(c.Value))
            empIDs.Add(Convert.ToInt32(r.Cells["Employee No"].Value));        
    }
}
```

At the end of the click event the global variable will be filled with the ID of the employees that have their SELECT cell clicked